# Kinect Motor Device Not Detected

Tags: usb, ubuntu-12.04, kinect

I'm trying to install a kinect on Ubuntu 12.04.
Unfortunately, lsusb shows that the motor device is not detected :

> Bus 002 Device 009: ID 045e:02c2 Microsoft Corp.
>
> Bus 002 Device 010: ID 045e:02ad Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Audio
>
> Bus 002 Device 011: ID 045e:02ae Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Camera

So when I try to run freenect-glview for example, I get this :

> Kinect camera test
>
> Number of devices found: 1
>
> Could not open device

It's been 2 weeks i'm looking for an answer, with no result.
A few people seems to have the same problem, but nobody never solve the problem.

Comment: have you tried running freenect-glview as root? maybe it's a permission problem

Comment: it's probably the new kinect model 1473.